# Select clients that didn't buy in the last 60 days- php

Tags: php

I have a database how lock like this:

email /  order date.

```
client1@gmail.com 13-02-2018
client2@gmail.com 02-02-2018
client3@gmail.com 24-01-2019
client3@gmail.com 24-06-2018
client3@gmail.com 24-04-2018
```

I have to select clients emails that didn't buy in the last 60 days.

for exemple "client3@gmail.com" has 3 orders 2 older that 60 days and one in the last 60days so I have to exclude this client. I have to extract just the clients that didn't buy in the last 60days.

```
$time60days = date('d-m-Y', strtotime(date('d-m-Y')) - 60*60*24*60);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `email` ORDER BY `email`.`email` ASC ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $h=0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $zi=$row["created_at"];
         if(strtotime($zi) < strtotime($time60days)) {
            echo "id: " . $row["order_id"]. " - Email: " . $row["email"]. " " . $row["created_at"]. "<br>";

           }
            $h++;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo $h;
$conn->close();
```

I have to extract just client 1 and 2 , not 3.

Comment: why you don't add a where clause in your sql ?

Comment: for the date? would that just select client3 just as well because he has an older order

Comment: why dont you use datediff in sql ?

Comment: Start with https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html Filter out those records where that maximum date is less than 60 days in the past next. All this can - and should - be done via SQL, not PHP.

Comment: Something like - SELECT email, max(created_at) as last_date FROM table GROUP BY  email HAVING last_date > 60 days.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, i will try

Comment: SELECT email, max(created_at) as last_date FROM emailtable GROUP BY email HAVING last_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 60 DAY ORDER BY `last_date` DESC

Answer (score 1):

You can try with MySQL `DATEDIFF()`,

```
SELECT email,MAX(order_date) FROM your_tbl_name GROUP BY email HAVING DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), order_date) >= 60 ORDER BY email ASC
```